# How to append elements to an Object when serializing with JMSSerializerBundle?

Tags: php, serialization, symfony

Here is what I want to do:

1. I've an object, let's say `Article` with two property `id` and `title`
2. I want to serialize it using JMSSerializerBundle, either in XML or JSON (but it should applies to any supported format)
3. While serializing, I want to append some informations so the serialized results looks like this:

   ```
   <article>
     <id>1</id>
     <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
     <slug>1-lorem-ipsum</slug>
   </article>
   ```

As you can see, the result has been appended the `<slug>` element which is actually not a property of the `Article` object.

I tried to dive in the code, and I tried to write a custom serialization handler. I tried several strategy like appending a dynamic object property but it never get serialized. I read a similar issue with the `stdClass` and I think the same problem applies, metadata doesn't exists for this property since it has been dynamically added to the object after instantiation.

I then decided to create a new XML element, but if I return my newly created element, this is the only which get serialized and it result in something like:

```
    <article>
      <slug>1-lorem-ipsum</slug>
    </article>
```

I also tried to return the entire document but it results in an error (a DOMElement is expected).

I'm little stuck and any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I wrote a handler to add an `avatar_url` property to my serialized User, have a look https://github.com/adrienbrault/SUPINFO-B3-YouFood-Server/blob/master/src/YouFood/ApiBundle/Serializer/Handler.php

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem with automatically adding a Link rel to each serialized object. I finally settled on creating a Link entity and an association to this in the entity to be serialized.
You could do the same with the slug.

This had the additional advantage of being able to dynamically edit the Links if e.g. the URL changed.